# Generation of postscript and merging using fop and Java

Tags: java, postscript, apache-fop

How to generate PS file using fop and Java, I want to merge multiple PS file into a single PS file using Java.

I have tried to generate PS file using fop but I am getting font embedded like some hex code such as:

```
currentfile eexec
743F8413F3636CA85A9FFEFB50B4BB27302A5A63F932884E18BF5153AD36053037D1C6CD04294AF6
A35612DB9108AC8514CB5C4A8469971B75A09F9E662068B0685490EA8C73F2DE2FBBCF85D15AB938
5E529DAB15A40D408002E88D0C107F711BC66BF0F2E92FDDC6B188F91EEB6B86050D5032E6ABCB11
E343C6D795217B5973972E99A9420651ACF3B8FD4CAD1DA4B00642AD077A5B86240F89F2BC011009
CB2CF173FF68E9A88F0018F187D5E036FE8D904F211842FF01AA7CAADDEB9E5A534FA3F90BDB8F6F
FE24F7AC6E7BD0A74CF29EBBA568F06579E7B94525361F129F4F81EE9D544CFEFB99016F6E9A016E
B88F88C24726C9A599025E44462A175261626CE6EBAFB69756CC45D96FA04CF97B4A02B39C9F19C2
877B8CE3851E452934959B271BE3E0B169FC27C16FD23870F5BD117BADD10D56110795B27E4C18B8
FC1D4F2E23D69F032AD8BD2BA0DD229DF0F7531E572FA98036D5B425C4014559DEBFE1A4E7751D76
9A35ED5B80952DCA3908E603FC74D8EAFDCEC4F7485178235EDD900910F0DAFA48A518EBFF47CAE5
DEDDE9F4CD4D7C145E4B251BCBAFE60D78443E0644A37FB449E0FC66563DF4C8A55D73D939F86D1F
1D034B251E7F0EA3F68A549B809EF2C2A2DEAE6BD87BA1911799C6D56B59EA08B6BB183DB097481B
6A3DBEDCAC24C85DD2E082C79227338E9231AD1DF384DB40D108413FFE0DA0192ABE57D70170871C
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
cleartomark
```

Answer (score 0):

PostScript is a programming language, there is no simple means to 'merge' two PostScript programs.

For many cases simply appending one program to the end of another will work, but there are PostScript programs which will defeat this simple-minded approach.

I don't understand why you have a problem with an embedded font, its part of the PostScript program and its going to need it.

Perhaps if you explained what you actually want to achieve, or at least **why** you want to 'merge' PostScript programs, it might be possible to help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply Kens. embedded font means font family is coming in postscript that's fine but i want to remove "currentfile eexec" from file. Merge: my requirement is like that to merge 2-3 ps file in one ps like pdf. i have done for pdf but this PS file not able to do. I am using confg file to generate ps by using fop and mime type postscript and pls suggest me any tool name that provide view of  multiple pages for ps. currently i am using Ghostscript studio to view or edit the ps file. Thanks

Comment: My confic file:<auto-rotate-landscape>false</auto-rotate-landscape> <font kerning="yes" embed-url="file:///C:/Users/user1/Font/Tondo-Bold.pfb">
     <font-triplet name="TondoCorpBld" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    </font> </fonts>

Comment: I do not understand why you would want to remove currentfile eexec from the PostScript program, if you do that it will break. There is no 'Ghostscript studio' that I'm aware of. Ghostscritp certainly will render PostScript, to a variety of devices. I'm afraid your config file means nothing to me. As I said, PostScript is a programming language, PostScript files are programs, you can't reasonably expect to alter them without understanding the language.

Comment: Thanks for reply, removing of currentfile due to file size, but now i understand its not worth to remove this font setting. how to merge two ps file into single one using java. their is any option for merge in java.

Comment: FWIW the 'currentfile eexec' is in fact the embedded font, hence why I say if you remove that section the program won't work as expected. I can't help you at all with Java.

Comment: Thanks kens, i got solution for merge using java.